# xamarin OnPlatform for clicked button

Tags: c#, xamarin

i can use OnPlatform on xamarin now

```
    <button text="{OnPlatform android=Hi , uwp=bey"}/>
```

but if i want to use it on the clicked even like:

```
     <button clicked="{OnPlatform android=Android_klik , uwp=Wpf_klik"}/>
```

then i have this error:

```
     Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
     Error      Position 16:34. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Clicked', or mismatching type between value and property.   $$  $$\MainPage.xaml
```

so what i can do for creating 2 click event on xaml ?

Comment: @SushiHangover can you show me how ?
i'm trying to connect to mysql
so for android and ios i'm using System.Data.CData.MySQL;
and for uwp using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `switch` (or `if`/`else`) on the `Device.RuntimePlatform`  property.

#### Example:

```
void someButton_Click_Handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
    {
        case Device.UWP:
            // do your UWP assignments...
            break;
        default:
            // do your Android & iOS assignments...
            break;
    }
}
```

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.runtimeplatform?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Device_RuntimePlatform